# AsyncTask - where is it better to process the code that I get back?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a remote call that I make and I am wondering where it is better to put this processing code:

```
        if ( result == null )
        {       
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Some error message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                                

        }
        else
        if ( result.equals( "all_problems_db_error" ))
        {
        Log.d( "AllBusinessesActivity" , "result: " + result )                                      
        }
        else
        {
            // Unwrap the stuff from the JSON string                
            String problem_title = null;
            String problem_id = null;

            try
            {
                JSONArray obj = new JSONArray(result);

                if ( obj != null )
                {
                    problems.clear();

                    for ( int i = 0; i < obj.length(); i++ )
                    {
                        JSONObject o = obj.getJSONObject(i);

                        problem_title = o.getString("problem_title");
                        problem_id = o.getString("problem_id");

                        Problem p = new Problem ( );
                        p.setProblemId(problem_id);                         
                        p.setProblemName(problem_title);

                        problems.add( p );
                    }

                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();             

                }                                   
            }
            catch ( Exception e )
            {
           // Do something :)
            }               
        }
```

Is it better to have it in the onPostExecute() or at the end or doInBackground() ?

I now do it in onPostExecute() but every once in a while I experience some slowness, and I have been reading that it might be better to do this in the doInBackground.

Could someone please explain to me the difference? And if I do this in the doInBackground() then what is the purpose of having the onPostExecute method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Is it better to have it in the onPostExecute()`

Since in your case there is no manipulation of any UI component, you can have the code in `doInBackground()`. But since you are showing a `toast` when the result is `null` you can check the result in `doInBackground()` and if the result is not null you can do the remaining processing on that `result` in the same function or else you can pass on to `onPostExecute()` where you can show the `toast`.

`at the end or doInBackground()`
Yes. You can have this code at the end of `doInBackground()` since this method runs on a non-UI thread and this will definitely reduce the slowness you experience.

The difference between both these method `doInBackground()` and `onPostExecute()` is simply that the former runs on a non-UI thread and the later on the UI-Thread.

`And if I do this in the doInBackground() then what is the purpose of having the onPostExecute method`

Usually the `doInBackground()` is used to perform time consuming operations. These operations may include activities like calling a webservice or fetching images from servers. In such cases (like fetching images from servers) you want that images to be displayed on your screen (which is your UI). After you fetch these resource you pass on the data to the `onPostExecute()` where you can update your UI since it runs on your UI thread.

Hope this explanation clears your doubt.

Comment: I am not sure - I gave an upvote.  The same thing happened to one of the other answers. I upvoted all 3.

Answer (score 2):

The `onPostExecute` method is useful when you need to do stuff on the UI Thread. In fact, you *cannot* do any manipulation of the UI in the `doInBackground` method.

So try to do all calculations / downloading of data etc. in the `doInBackground` method, and only the manipulation of your UI in the `onPostExecute` method.